# How to subscribe and pass along collection changed event of child observable collection?

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have a ViewModel wrapping an instance of a model object and acting as an interface between the model and the View. In my case, the model has a collection that I connect to the view with an observable collection in the view model.

For instance :

```cs
    public class NotificationBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] String fieldName = null)
        {
            if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
            field = value;
            RaiseChangedEvent(fieldName);
            return true;
        }

        protected T SetProperty<T>(T property, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(property, value)) RaiseChangedEvent(propertyName);
            return value;
        }

        protected void RaiseChangedEvent(string changedObjectName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(changedObjectName));
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : NotificationBase
    {
        public ViewModel(ref Model model)
        {
            _model = model ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("Model cannot be null");
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Thing> ViewModelCollection
        {
            get { return _model.ModelCollection; }
            set { _model.ModelCollection = SetProperty(_model.ModelCollection, value); }
        }

        private Model _model { get; set; }
    }
```

My question is : how do I make the view know when `_model.Collection` and thus `ViewModelCollection` are changed ?

Note : `Model.Collection` actually is an `ObservableCollection` but I don't know how to pass the `CollectionChanged` event along to the ViewModel and then to the View.

Comment: Two things: (1) If the property `ViewModelCollection` changes (i.e., it represents/gets assigned a new/different ObservableCollection instance; note that this would also include the case of _model itself changing), fire a property change notification, in the same way you would do for any other property in your ViewModel. (2) The property provides the ObservableCollection, and you don't need to separately "provide" the CollectionChanged event; because the CollectionChanged event is (obviously) an inseparatable part of the ObservableCollection provided by this property...

Comment: Thank you for your insight, though in my case that does't work if the ModelCollection gets changed outside ViewModelCollection setter (eg in another view)

Comment: What precisely do you mean with "_if the ModelCollection gets changed_"? What precisely and exactly changes how?

Comment: I have a NavigationView menu and my backing data may be changed in other Views.

Comment: That's still rather vague and does not explain in the slightest what precisely and exactly changes with regard to the ModelCollection... (I am not asking you to explain your program to me, i just ask about what **exact** change happens -or can happen- to the ModelCollection when you were saying "_if the ModelCollection gets changed outside ViewModelCollection setter_")

Comment: I see that's not what I understood sorry for that.
Well pretty much anything can happen : elements of the collection can be added, reordered, removed or individually modified. These changes are made through a DataGrid directly bound to the collection.

Comment: Okay, that's no problem. Remember, the ObservableCollection itself possesses the CollectionChanged event and will raise such corresponding to the changes you make to the collection (addition, removal or reordering/replacing of items to/from/in the collection). It doesn't matter where or who adds/removes items to the collection, as the collection itself takes care of collection change notifications...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193223/discussion-between-marcel-barc-and-elgonzo).